# Magic connection between service and controller (angular)

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

if i have two controllers and a service which communicates between the controllers how does the scope of one controller effects the value in the service? For me it looks like setting the controllers value with the value from the service and thats it, but somehow the controller can change the services value without calling any setter method? Is it a good and performant way to handle the service? 
I searched for it but couldn't find a good answer. Answers and examples to docs and blogposts are welcome, thanks.

```
// App.js    
angular.module("myApp",[]);
angular.module("myApp").service("shareSvc", function(){
    var _items = {};

    return {
        items: _items
    }
});
angular.module("myApp").controller("controller1", function($scope,     shareSvc){
    $scope.items = shareSvc.items;
    $scope.items.magic = "magic";
});
angular.module("myApp").controller("controller2", function($scope,     shareSvc){
    $scope.items = shareSvc.items;
});

//HTML
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="controller1">
        <div>{{items.magic}}</div>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="controller2">
        <div>{{items.magic}}</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I created a fiddle which shows the behavior in an example.

https://jsfiddle.net/w0pq3cp8/1/

Comment: You are equivalently calling shareSvc.items.magic = "magic";

Answer (score 0):

This works because JavaScript uses pass by reference for objects.

Since `_items` refers to an object, references to it also refer to the same object. So when your service returns `{ items: _items }` it is returning a reference to the object that `_items` refers to. Then the controllers set their scope variables to refer to the same object. After that changing the value of a property on the scope variables - like `items.magic` is a change to that base object `_items` referred to.

This is fine to do but it does show that `_items` is not really private so the underscore is misleading.